# What exactly is the 'cpumin.exe' process which runs in the background and takes up 100% of the CPU? It happens whenever I run a Java program

Tags: java, process, cpu

I've been programming in Java this morning, and although I've stopped now, my CPU has been running at 100% even though it should be idle. The task manager shows that a single process called 'cpumin.exe' is causing this. I've traced the file to a folder called 'javacache'.

Could anyone please explain what I can do to stop this? As whenever I kill the process, it just starts again.

Thanks

Comment: The `javacache` folder might serve as a distraction, and probably has nothing to do with Java, unless your Java deployment cache is the same location. In case, you ought to update your JDK/JRE to 1.6 u26.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too!

Comment: This is quite likely some kind of malware, and it is probably using your machine to send spam.  See http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=dd6da7e7b46f199edc8e4a81b2ae5e1e

Answer (score 2):

Me too faced this problem before 2-3 days. When I just run my browser(Firefox) cpumin.exe starts and it consumes 100% of cpu and fans run faster. Still I couldn't be able to fix the problem....

I fixed it...............:)

I used process explorer and locate those files. 
They were on C:\Documents and Settings\Anuruddha\javacache\ folder.
Parent process was timesync.exe and the child was cpumin.exe
I tried to delete these files. But couldn't be able to delete "timesync" bcz it's said that it is in use.

So I created new admin account and log to the new account. By logging to newly created account, i was able to delete the timesync file on previous account. Now I'm working on old account and It works fine...:)

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across this EXE and neither has google.  http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cpumin.exe

It appears you are the first and possibly the only person who can say what it does.

Comment: That's exactly why I decided to ask here, because google returned no results :/

Comment: Can you find it on your file systems and look at the EXEs properties eg manufacturer?

Comment: Just checked - there are no details attributed with it. Just that it was last modified at the beginning of May. Strange that it should be actually showing itself today though. I changed it's permissions, but I doubt that would actually stop it if it is infact a virus. Running a scan as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

I found [a single thread on the internet mentioning this process](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=http://www.linhadefensiva.org/forum/index.php%3Fshowtopic%3D129554&ei=o-_1TYDEIorn0QHg4bTtDA&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEcQ7gEwBQ&prev=/search%3Fq%3D%252Bcpumin.exe%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D997%26bih%3D912%26prmd%3Divns) (Google-translated), and the invidual thinks he may have a virus. You should explore that possibility.

Comment: Ive checked out that thread, however from what I could see, the focus wasnt on this particular .exe. I'll look into it though - thanks.