# Some one help me please, cpumun.exe irritating me

Tags: process, preprocessor, cpu, cpu-usage, resource-monitor

My CPU is running at 100% even though it should be idle. The task manager shows that a single process called 'cpumin.exe' is causing this.
Could anyone please explain what I can do to stop this? As whenever I kill the process, it just starts again.

I have noticed kind of relationship between this process and network, because when I unplug the network cable the computer works well.
And there is something else when I give this process the order "Suspend process" and when you open the "Analyze Wait Chain" I found that this process have this message "One or more threads of cpumin.exe are waiting to finish network I/O".

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Someone else had a similar problem here ...

[What exactly is the 'cpumin.exe' process which runs in the background and takes up 100% of the CPU? It happens whenever I run a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329535/what-exactly-is-the-cpumin-exe-process-which-runs-in-the-background-and-takes-u)

Probably best to do a full virus scan just in case. According to http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=dd6da7e7b46f199edc8e4a81b2ae5e1e, it could be some sort of mass mailer.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

Click Start > Run > (type "cmd.exe" without quotation) > Enter

a Command line (black screen will appear) type the following:

```
taskkill /fi "imagename eq cpumun.exe" /f /t
```

The above command will surely kill the task and all of its child processes and tree.

Comment: He already said that he kills the process and it starts again.

Comment: killing the process from the taskmanager window is different from the command line I proposed, because the command will /FORCE /TREE kill all of the process and its children before any sub process will have the time to create another process which is the case when using TaskManager in Windows

Comment: But then he reboots his computer and the process starts again.... Better to treat the cause and not the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

cpumin.exe appears to be a virus, see:

http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=dd6da7e7b46f199edc8e4a81b2ae5e1e